# How to set auto height for flex element?

Tags: html, css

Here are two flex divs:

```
<div style="display:flex">
   <div class="content">Content</div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

How to increase the height if first block if content is not fit inside?

I tried:

```
.content {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try align-items: stretch. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be solved using `100vh` instead of `100%`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .content {
        flex: 1;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100vh; // modified
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div style="display:flex">
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div>TEST</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content {
  height: max-content;
}

In my opinion this problem is solved by max-content.
Here is height: max-content.
Give me your opinion. 
Thank you.
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
   <div class="content">Content</div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Part of your answer that is not code, is formatted in your code block. I think it would be more clear if you put that part outside of the code block. See here for markdown help if needed: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help